# hashtable search is slower than linkedlist

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a tree structure, where each node contains its name and a reference to it using hashtable.

I'm trying to search for a node in the structure using linked list once, and once using the hashtable. 
The linked list search is faster than the hashtable. What could be the situations that hashtable search is slower than linked list ?

here is the code the does both search

```
 /* if there is a hasthable defined in the dpal object search using it */
 if(!htbl){
    for (i= 0, j = 0; dpal_path[i] != 0; i++)
    {
      if (dpal_path[i] == sep)
      {
        khash_str_t key;
        khiter_t entry;
        const char *token = &dpal_path[j];
        size_t length = i-j;
        j=i+1;
        htbl = &start_obj->obj_string_htbl;
        key.str = token;
        key.len = length;
        /* look for the dpal object in the hashtable */
        entry = kh_get_str2int32(htbl, key);
        if (entry != kh_end(htbl)) {
          start_obj=(dpal_obj_t*)kh_value(htbl, entry); 
          result = start_obj;
        }
        else{
          result=DPAL_OBJ_HANDLE_INVALID;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  /* otherwise search for it using linked list structure */
  else{
    for (i= 0, j = 0; dpal_path[i] != 0; i++)
    {
      if (dpal_path[i] == sep)
      {
        const char *token = &dpal_path[j];
        size_t length = i-j;
        j=i+1;
        if(start_obj != NULL){
          start_obj = start_obj->child;
        }
        while ((start_obj != NULL)){
          if(strncmp(token, start_obj->static_props.name, length) == 0){
            result = start_obj;
            break; 
          }
          /* get next handle in flat hierarchy */
          start_obj=start_obj->next;
          if(start_obj == NULL){
            result = DPAL_OBJ_HANDLE_INVALID;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The time it takes to search a linked list depends heavily on the length of the list. With one or two elements, it would be *extremely* fast.

Comment: I have made a loop and it loops for 100 times, and the path is so long so that linked list gets slower, but it doesn't, still its faster than the hash table

Comment: 100 elements is not a lot. Also, are the results statistically significant?

Comment: @amit, linked list taskes 11 ms while hashtable takes 14 ms

Comment: @AhmedSaleh (1) Repeat it with 1,000,000 elements. (2) is it [statistical significant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance). (3) For 100 elements I bet array/vector will be faster than both.

Comment: @amit You mean by elements, a search path or a linked elements of 1.000.000 ?

Comment: `if (!htbl) {...}` it looks like you have your logic inverted... BTW: what **is** htable? where is it defined ?

Comment: @wildplasser I'm inverting the logic if I'm using the linkedlist, then I invert it back If I want to use hashtable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will mainly depend on how many elements there are to search through on each iteration of your for loop (i.e. how long the linked list formed by start_obj->next is) and how computationally expensive kh_get_str2int32, kh_end and kh_value are. Without knowing the average length of the linked list and the implementation of your hash table functions it's impossible to give a more definite answer.